# How to disable internal terminal while debugging for .Net Core projects in Visual Studio 2022 preview

Tags: .net, visual-studio, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2022

As the header says:
I want the console-window (old school) to popup on a ASP.NET Core Web API project when debugging.

Currently using Visual Studio 2022 Version 17.5.0 Preview 1.0.

This is how the integrated terminal runs like and is not what I want:
[image: Integrated terminal example]

There are no options to select in the launchSettings.json for the project

```
  "profiles": {
    "http": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "dotnetRunMessages": true,
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "swagger",
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:5184",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
```

Config for debugging:
[image: Debugoptions for https profile]

**To reproduce**

1. Create an ASP.NET Core Web API project with default choices.
2. Change profile to "https" like this:

[image: https profile change to debug]

3. Press F5 to debug

I have Visual Studio 2019 and it works as expected there, with an console popup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to Tools → Options → Projects and Solutions → ASP .NET Core and change the "Run web server in" option to "External Console"

[image: image showing option to change to external console]

After doing so, you should have an external command prompt open like so:

[image: external command prompt showing app running]

Comment: Spot on Timothy! Searched and tried a lot of combination, but this option never showed while searching in options page. Thank you so much!